# How to split doctrine entity into more domain entities in different bounded contexts?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design

I am trying my first steps in DDD ([Domain-driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)) field. I love the wise rule, that you should split your entities into many smaller, context-specific entities (for example `User` entity tends to overgrow almost in every non-ddd or poorly designed application). But what are common options on how to do it (effectively) in php using Doctrine?

Let's say I have two Bounded contexts: `Store` and `Invoicing`

Each of them has two domain entities:
for Store BC it's `FirstTimeCustomer` and `RecurrentCustomer`
for Invoicing BC it's `VatCustomer` and `NonVatCustomer`

Now, in my infrastructure layer I want them all be saved in same (at least base) table to be able to reference them by general `UserId` (Uuid). The problem for me is, how to do that, so I can use advantage of doctrine automapping in my repository implementations.

I read about Single Table Inheritance or [Class Table Inheritance](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) that may be solution, but:

I need to be able to work with `User` of same Uuid as it was different type in each context.

I need to be able to return some `AbstractStoreCustomer` aka `FirstTimeCustomer` or `RecurrentCustomer` on `$storeCustomerRepository->find(1);` in Store BC.

And to return some `AbstractInvoicingCustomer` aka `VatCustomer` or `NonVatCustomer` on `$invoicingCustomerRepository->find(1);` in Invoicing BC.

But it seems that I am forced here to chose what BC I want specific identity of entity bound to. So it does not make sense in context of DDD to me at all.

I also read about [Mapped Superclasses](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses), that looks like option too, but:

> This means that One-To-Many associations are not possible on a mapped
>   superclass at all.

And I need `Customer` to have relation to orders, that should be available in both entities (an also possibly not want it to be available is some new type of `User` entity in new BC).

I came to conclusion that I should be suspicious that I am missing something, is that? How should I achieve breaking god entity into smaller context specific ones?

Comment: What is a `User` in your case? Is any body that authenticates? Some users will become `Customers`?

Comment: Yes, user is anybody that authenticates and any user is also Customer (of specific type) in other BCs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will start with some general rules. 
When thinking DDD you must reject any thoughts about persistence (tables and primary keys and the like). You must design your aggregate roots and entities as if you will store them in a file. When you design the models, if a thought about tables or ORM comes to your mind you fail to do DDD; take a step back and restart.

As I see, you started OK by splitting your models by the bounded contexts. If you do not split them by BCs you end up with gigantic models that try to encompass all the behavior and then the persistence will affect the performance, because, in DDD, the aggregates are persisted in one single transaction. One other thing, try to avoid inheritance and use composition.

That being said, lets talk about your business.
In the `Authentication` BC, there are `Users` that can authenticate, with some credentials. In the `Store` BC there are `Customers` that buy things. In the `Invoice` BC, there are also `Customers` but a different model (a different class if you want). In the `Shipping` BC there are also `Customers` but again, a different model. These `Customer` models share some properties along the BCs, like `name` and `id`. So, you use the `id` to identify a person from the real life but use different models to encapsulate their behavior depending on the context.

I think that you should not have a `AbstractStoreCustomer`, you should have only `Customer` and try to isolate what differentiate them in abstract class/interface, like `BuyingHistoryProfile` with 2 implementation `FirstTimeCustomer` and `RecurrentCustomer`. This class should contain only behavior regarding buying profile and it should be referenced by every`Customer` in the `Store` BC. Similarily, try to extract a class in the `Invoicing` BC for the price calculation.

Now that we've created the models, we can think about persistence. For every bounded context create a `Customer` table, that contains the shared properties (`name` and  `id`) and the specific properties (`buyingHistoryProfile` for the `Store` BC, `priceCalculationStrategy` for the `Invoicing` BC etc).

If you wonder that there is a degree of data duplication then you are right, but it is normal, it is necessary to decouple the models. This duplicate data is synchronized when the `User` in the `Authentication` BC change its name: you update all the other models right then. From this point of view, `Invoice` and `Store` BC are down-streams, they use data from the `Authentication` BC; it depends on your business when the update is initiated.

Being a fan of Event-driven architectures, I recommend you to take a look at CQRS (and even Event Sourcing). I think that these architectures fit well in this application. CQRS could make your models 10 times cleaner, I tell you from my experience. With Event Sourcing it is very probable that you won't even have to use an `ORM`. You could use an `ORM` on the read side, if you really like them or you *can't* leave them. I personally don't like (and don't use) `ORM`s.

Comment: I agree that ORMs can often do more harm than good.  However, I would like to point out that you can create an entity manager specific to a given BC.  Each entity manager would have it's own set of entity classes.  This avoids trying to design a once size fits all Customer entity.  Multiple entity managers can perhaps ease the transition away from ORMs.

Comment: @constantin-galbenu Hi, thank you for your response. You are right about models first and persistence then. Actually, I am doing DDD on brown field, so when I am adding new feature, I do that in BC beside legacy system. And I also have simple CQRS (ES not implemented yet) - I have split everything into Command and Queries. But unfortunately I am still not satisfied with that multiple tables for each BC. That involves that data synchronization and I would like to not overengineer it, just leave it as possibility for future refactoring... There is so much new and I dont want to add more in haste

Comment: @Tom `CQRS` is a long road and `Event Sourcing` even longer but the reward is awesome.

Comment: @cerad That idea about EM for each BC is interesting. So I can define `InvoicingCustomer` entity and have it mapped by EM in Invoice BC to same table `users` as entity `BuyingCustomer` mapped by EM in Shop BC? It seems then that I can have data for InvoicingCustomer and BuyingCustomer in same table with same ID. And I also can have different and even common columns to be mapped to any properties in each entity... And i do not need to synchronize data. But, is it really possible? How about creatng schema, when I have multiple EM with differrent entities mapped to same table?

Comment: @constantin-galbenu Yes, I feel that. I know I am moving towards it, but implementing ES and data synchronization between distributed systems now would be just for "I want it to be nice and fit it to some dogma I still dont fully get (why i should do something and cant do something)". I would rather choose path where i get why i need to do it like that in particular case where i did it initially simply or naive, because right now i really do not need to build distributed system. It's okay for me now to just build it to be somehow open for that possibility in future.

Comment: @Tom - Yes, multiple entity managers are practical.  Check the docs for details.  Probably need to do your own mapping and schema generation.  Remember, DDD is for applications with complex business logic.  It will take extra effort on your side and you should not expect too much out of CRUD based tools.